# Bluetooth Low Energy : bluetoothctl - invalid response to read

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot

Some background information:
The sensor im trying to read the characteristics from is part of the IoT-starterkit: Wunderbar. Originally the sensors where designed to connect with a mainboard which would than send the data received from the sensors to a cloud.
Sadly the mainboard is not working for me, so i used my raspberry Pi 3 to replace it.
Currently i'm able to read standard characteristics defined by bluetooth, such as the Battery level, Manufacturer Name String, etc..

My question is focused on reading characteristics of a Primary Service which is "unknown" to bluetoothctl.

I'm not sure whether the data can't be interpreted correctly or if i'm missing some kind of authentication.